# How to take the database backup

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server 2000

I want to take the database backup at application running time.

In my application i have database backup option, when i click the button it has to take the database backup upto current time.

How to make a query for taking the database backup

Need Query Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [BACKUP DATABASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa225964%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) statement, for example:

```
BACKUP DATABASE myDatabase -- myDatabase is your database name
TO DISK='d:\backup\myDatabase.bak' -- this is the path to backup
```

Comment: If the database is in use means i can take the backup...?

Comment: Note that the path has to be a path accessible to the server service, not the client application (important if these are on different machines, or running under different user accounts)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I recommend todo backup for price. it offers comprehensiv backup solution for  SQL server/ Exchange server. for more information, you can go [its website](http://www.todo-backup.com/backup-resource/sql-backup-software/backup-sql-server-2000.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Usually a statement like BACKUP DATABASE databasename does the trick but check Sql server help for info about all options and parameters like backup location, mode, compression etc...

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can choose what type of backup (full, differential, log) you need to perform with the "Backup database..." command.

Examples:

Full backup:

BACKUP DATABASE "database_name" TO DISK = 'D:\backupDatabase-Full.bak'
GO

Differential backup:

BACKUP DATABASE "database_name" TO DISK = 'D:\backupDatabase-Diff.bak' WITH DIFFERENTIAL 
GO